# Can't match "> quote"

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm trying to match everything after a blockquote mark (>), but for whatever reason it's not working.

```
if (preg_match("/> (.*)\n/",$line,$matches) !== false){
    echo $matches[1];
}
```

I tried matching things after some other marks and all of them worked with the same function for example:

```
if (preg_match("/# (.*)\n/",$line,$matches) !== false){
    echo $matches[1];
}
```

works fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Question lacks a source sample. (Which probably obfuscates the /multiline nature of the cause.)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$line='<b>huh</b>yep yes';
preg_match('/\/.*>(.*)(\n*)/mi',$line,$matches);
print_r($matches);// echo $matches[1];
?>
```

i run your code inside a place where usually isn't design to run php.
(i wrote a text filter that act as a plugin inside EditPlus [made inside free Koreea] )

[image]